# regex_substr: regular expression to extract the comma separated string literals

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

The following regular expression separates the comma separated plain values

```
(SELECT regexp_substr(:pCsv,'[^,]+', 1, level) 
 FROM DUAL 
 CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:pCsv, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL);
```

Example:

```
300100033146068, 300100033146071 , 300100033146079
```

returns

```
300100033146068
300100033146071
300100033146079
```

This works fine if we use the regular expression with SQL IN operator

```
select * 
from mytable 
where t.mycolumn IN (SELECT regexp_substr(:pCsv,'[^,]+', 1, level) 
                     FROM DUAL 
                     CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:pCsv, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL);
```

But this query is not working if the comma separated value is a single quoted string literal

```
'one' , ' two' , 'three'
```

Comment: How about `[^,']+` ?

Answer (score 2):

As sln mentioned in the comments, your regular expression is matching any number of non-`,` characters.  That means it will match `'one'`, not `one` as you expect.

To exclude the single quotes and spaces, you'll need to add them to the excluded characters list.

Your new inner query should look like:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(:pCsv,'[^,'' ]+', 1, level)
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:pCsv, '[^,'' ]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
```

Note that we have to use `''` to represent a single quote because it appears within another string.